# Backstretch.js not working on element but working on body

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I cannot figure out how to get backstretch to work on a div, It works 100% when just applying to the body, no errors.  But when I try to get to work on a `<div>` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'backstretch'

I've been searching on here for an answer and Its seem most issues were to do with calling multipal jQuery files or re-ordering the way its backstretch is being called.  Ive tried this and still no joy.

Has anyone any Ideas?...maybe I've been staring at this too long.

I can provide some code or a link to the site if necessary.

EDIT*

I have a div with ID "test"

```
$("#test").backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
```

EDIT*
http://wearebabble.triple-tested.com/global/view

Comment: Some code is helpful. How are you attaching it to the `a` element?

Comment: I'm just using the example taken from the backstretch website       <script type="text/javascript">      $("#test").backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
</script>

Comment: If you post questions or answers check the preview to make sure, that it is well formatted and readable. e.g. if you have tags like `<div>` in your text, you need to place them between \` (\`<div>\`) otherwise they are not visible.

Comment: To your question. The error message tells you that the jQuery object has no method `backstretch` this indicates that you did not load the script file for the `backstretch` plugin. Which scripts do you load and in what order?

Comment: Thanks, I shall make sure.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the library before your code.

Comment: In my header I have jQuery being loaded 1st, then backstretch.js and finally in the footer I have call attaching it to my div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version.

https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch

Change log at the bottom of the screen says the feature you are using was added in 2.0.

You are using 1.2.8.